# How do I Run React App on Nginx with a node.js backend on AWS EC2?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am trying to run a react app with Node.js backend on the Nginx server.

Here's my server block in the nginx.conf file:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/folder-name/frontend/build;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        }
        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;



        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

The `build` folder contains the compiled react js code(using `npm run build`)
Node.js backend is running on port 5000 using pm2/forever.

After restarting the Nginx Server, the react UI appears on the server IP but the UI is distorted.
Also, I am not able to access my backend APIs on `MyIP/api/endpoint`.

What am i doing wrong.? This nginx configuration was built from SO and other online resources so there's a huge probabilty that it could be wrong. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

The issue is you are setting the API proxy for the root (`/`). The correct one should look like this:

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/folder-name/frontend/build;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    }
```

If you don't have `/api` path in your Node.js, you will need a rewrite rule for it like this:

```
        location /api {
            rewrite ^/api/?(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host; 
        }
```

Comment: This is the perfect and simplest solution!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can host both API and static files (build files of your front-end) on the same domain or host. Below, you can find a server block for a sample API hosted on port 3000 and static HTML files at a root location being served on port 80.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {    
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html;
        error_page 404 index.html;
    }
    location /api/ {    
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    }
}
```

You can access the front-end at `http://localhost/<blah...>` and the API at `http://localhost/api/<blah...>` (please note how `/api` is handled in the URL here and the server block above). Replace `localhost` with your domain name.

Answer (score 1):

I had experience that.Please check my image file
[image]

This configuration is running successfully on aws.
Your mistakes is proxy area. Please change like that.

```
location /api/ {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/
}
```

If you want, I can **HELP** you.

Answer (score 0):

> What am i doing wrong.?

One issue is with your `proxy_pass` directive. You are missing trailing slash `/`

```
...
location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        }
...
```

First, try this and share your result.